# How can I modify values with ref on structs. c#

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        struct Ball
    {
        public string name;
        public int    num;
        public string   city;
        public torneoCanicas(string name, int num, string city)
        {
            this.name= name;
            this.num = num;
            this.city= city;
        }
    }
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ball joan = new Ball("JOAN",12,"Vilanova");
```

So I want to modify the value of this struct using ref. Someone know how?
Like:

```
static void modify(ref ball){
     Ball[0].name="New name";
     Ball[0].num=54;
     Ball[0].city="Barcelona";
}
```

And that doesn't work.
I want to use a structure to be able to modify data "globally".
And I know that to be able to modify I need to use reference, but I don't know how to use it with structures.
There is another way?

Comment: you don't have an array in your example and your constructor name `torneoCanicas` differs from your struct name `balls`

Comment: You should use name `ball` Not `balls`, And It should starts with Capital character: `Ball`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. What you asking for is unclear. What is your goal & your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env & data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Can you add more code and check/clarify your question, please? What array ? What `ref`?

Comment: Assuming you have an array, with a struct like that, you shouldn't be able to modify the struct, you would have to override it with a new one. You might want to look into classes instead of struct for your use case.

Comment: @Muaath: Why would a parameter name start with a capital letter?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I mean use PascalCasing in naming structs and classes. I didn't say parameters, See: [Names of Classes, Structs, and Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Also I suggest using PascalCasing in field naming. See [Name of fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-fields)

Comment: @Muaath: That fields part is only for public/protected fields, which are generally a bad idea anyway. But when you referred to "ball" in your first comment, I assumed you meant the parameter because in the *current* post that's the only `ball` identifier. I see now that the post has changed significantly since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass it by reference so it doesn't get copied on your method:

```
   static void modify(ref Ball ball){
        ball.name="New name";
        ball.num=54;
        ball.city="Barcelona";
    }
```

And call your method like:

```
modify(ref joan); // joan is the name of the variable in your example
```

I've made a sample here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ae2ZAV

By the way, your naming conventions are hard to follow :-)

PS: that said, make sure you actually need a `struct` there, and not a `class` (for which you wouldn't need any `ref` to do what you want). Explaining the differences between those would be WAY out of the scope of this question.